# In jQuery add a list when hovered?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to apply a variable to a listed item when it's hovered on. The listed item is in HTML like this:

```
<ul class="listed-items">
 <li class="navigation"><a href="/">Root Path</a></li>
 <li class="navigation"><a href="/something">Something Else</a></li>
 <li class="navigation dropdown-service"><a href="/websites">Website</a></li>
```

Basically I want to hit the last list item and make it hoverable and then display it's own listed websites.

So I have the following:

```
var service_list = [{name: "Google", url: "www.google.com"}, {name: "Bing", url:"www.bing.com"}];
```

Then I have for the hover:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{          
$("li").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".dropdown-service").show()},
    function () {
    $(this).find(".dropdown-service").hide()
});
});
```

I honestly don't think that's the best way for the hover to work unless I should be putting something in the show for the variable.

I've tried the following to no avail, albeit no errors:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.dropdown-service').show(service_list.name)},
  function(){
    $(this).find(".dropdown-service").hide();
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Don't understand what you're trying to do. Inside `$('li').hover`, `this` will be the `li`. So `$(this).find('.dropdown-service')` won't find anything, because the "dropdown-service" class is already on the `li`. There are no elements _within_ the `li` with that class, only the `li` itself. But unless your CSS has hidden all the content within `li` elements, then they're already visible, so using show() won't do anything (hide() would hide it , if the selector was correct).

Comment: Are you trying to append the content of serviceList to the li? show() and hide() are for showing and hiding existing elements, not adding things to the element. Perhaps you want `.append()`? And then maybe you want to `.remove()` those elements again when the hover ends? Or maybe just `.empty()` the `li` completely? Try reading the jQuery docs to find out what functions are available and exactly what they do.

Comment: Looking to create a nested list under website based. So I guess append/remove would work based on hovering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i guess this is what you really looking for

try this. and this is jquery 3.3.1
https://jsfiddle.net/eaje2ywt/19/

```
$('.dropdown-service').on('mouseover',function(ev){
  ev.stopPropagation();
  for(var i=0;i<service_list.length;i++) {
 var s = $("<li>"+service_list[i].name+"</li>");
 $('.websites').append(s);
}
```

Comment: Not completely working for my data but it's actually what I need to get there.

Comment: how you get data? from any api?  let me see the example response